# wild card support in Embedded Jetty WebAppContext

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am looking for wild card support in Embedded Jetty WebAppContext contextPath but could not work out any.
I have following code for my shopping webapp:

```
String path = "/shopping";
WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext(WEBAPP_PATH, path);
contexts.addHandler(wac);
```

I want that if access http://ip:port/shopping/*anything*, it should load my above webapp. But it does not. I also tried with path = "/shopping/*" and it did not work either.
Can anyone here please help me if it is possible or not or am I doing something wrong here.

EDIT:
I am deploying a webapp (flatten content) on Jetty and can access it successfully using http://host:port/shopping. 
To achieve this, I created a WebAppContext(wac) with webappPath to resource folder and context-path as /shopping. I added this wac to handler list and attached it to server (Jetty Server).
Now, what I want is to access this webapp using http://host:port/shopping/. Whatever I provide after shopping in url, my same webapp should get loaded.

UPDATE:
Further following on this, I tried below but it did not work out.

> ServletContextHandler context = new
>   ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
>               context.setContextPath("/shopping");
>               ServletHolder staticHolder = new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet());
>               staticHolder.setInitParameter("resourceBase", webAppPath);
>               staticHolder.setInitParameter("pathInfoOnly", "true");
>               context.addServlet(staticHolder, "/*");
>               context.setWelcomeFiles(new String[] { "index.html", "index.htm", "index.jsp" });
>               contexts.addHandler(context);

Now, if I try /shopping, it works but /shopping/abc does not. It seems wildcard matching is not working. If I use /home instead of /*, /shopping/home works. Can anyone please help me here.

My requirement is to server weabAppPath for any /shopping/* url.

Comment: You are serving static content only?  No servlets? no filters? no JSP? no security constraints? no HttpSessions?

Comment: Yes static content and REST only, no servlets and JSP. Security constraints are there as a separate handler attached to server.

Comment: REST means you have dynamic content, which means you have a servlet.  It also means that Jetty isn't serving the static content, your REST library is (typical for Jersey library).

Comment: No, Jetty is serving static context using org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext as mentioned in my question. REST is being served by Jersey using ServletContainer.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt. I update the question. Can you please help now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got it working. Below will serve webapp for /shopping and /shopping/anything/* requests.

```
String path = "/shopping";   
WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext(WEBAPP_PATH, path); 
contexts.addHandler(wac); 
wac.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new WebappServlet()), "/anything/*");

public class WebappServlet extends HttpServlet 
{    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException     {               
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.html").forward(request, response);  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your short code snippet (really there's almost nothing to work with here), your WebAppContext has no servlets declared.

Nothing in that WebAppContext will be called to handle the incoming request.

A WebAppContext is assigned to a `context-path`, which has a syntax of `/<path>`, there is no wildcard support within a `context-path`.

What you are looking for is wildcard support in a `url-pattern`, which only exists for Servlets and Filters.

Do this, create a `ShoppingAnythingServlet` and set it to the `url-pattern` of `/*` and then you'll get all requests to that new Servlet.

From within that code, use the `HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()` to obtain what that */anything* is.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joakim. There is no servlet here. It is just loading the webapp index.html from war. It seems we cannot put wild cars in context path.

Comment: Is there any other way to load webapp on wild card path.

Comment: Your description of your problem is not sufficient.  Instead of focusing on the detail of wildcards or context paths or whatnot, describe (edit your question) what goal you are attempting to accomplish.  There's likely a completely different path to that goal that can be taken.